# canvas draw rounded rectangle in reverse?

Tags: canvas, rounded-corners, shapes

I apologise in advance for asking this, I was kindly provided with some code to draw a rounded corner rectangle progress bar which was great:

http://jsfiddle.net/P2qTq/

I need to reverse the drawing of the rectangle but I can't for the life of me manage it

http://jsfiddle.net/P2qTq/7/

I tried changing the points at which the 4 lines and 4 corners are drawn so it starts with the top left corner but I'm making a total mess of it:

```
    var startT = 0;
    var startTR = horizLineLength;
    var startR = startTR + cornerLength;
    var startBR = startR + vertLineLength;
    var startB = startBR + cornerLength;
    var startBL = startB + horizLineLength;
    var startL = startBL + cornerLength;
    var startTL = startL + vertLineLength;
```

to

```
var startTL = 0;
var startL = startTL + cornerLength;
var startBL = startL + vertLineLength;
var startB = startBL + cornerLength;
var startBR = startB + horizLineLength;
var startR = startBR + cornerLength;
var startTR = startR + vertLineLength;
var startT = startTR = cornerLength;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
drawPercentRect(ui.value);
```

Do this:

```
drawPercentRect(100-ui.value);
```